# R - Lattice xyplot - How do you add error bars to groups and summary lines?

Tags: r, lattice, standard-error

I'm posting this question because the very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678494/r-add-error-bars-to-different-groups-in-xyplot) has not been answered until now.

I have been asked to plot the mean +/- SEM of my whole cohort of patients over the `xyplot()` that depicts the values of all patients. The data used represents intraoperative cardiovascular findings  from patients undergoing surgery.

This is my `data.frame` called `df`

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("DE", "JS", "KG", "MK", "TG", "WT"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L), .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", 
    "T8"), class = "factor"), Dobut = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor"), DobutDose = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, NA), CI = c(1.4, 2.3, 1.3, 1.8, 2.1, 
    2, 2.1, 2.1, 2.3, 1.9, 1.6, 2, 2.4, 2.7, 2.6, 2.7, 2.6, 2.3, 
    2.4, 2.6, 0.9, 2.5, 2.1, 1.6, 1.5, 1.8, 2, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 
    2, 2.4, 2.3, 2.6, 2.4, 2, 2.2, 1.6, 2.1, 2.5, 2.8), SvO2 = c(57L, 
    65L, 47L, 45L, 51L, 60L, 56L, 70L, 85L, 75L, 79L, 82L, 73L, 
    77L, 78L, 73L, 71L, 73L, 80L, 74L, 41L, 66L, 51L, 51L, 49L, 
    54L, 68L, 48L, 80L, 70L, 71L, 69L, 74L, 79L, 77L, 77L, 75L, 
    74L, 70L, 79L, 80L, 79L), SVRI = c(4000L, 1983L, 4000L, 2444L, 
    1981L, 2120L, 2514L, 2971L, 2157L, 3747L, 4300L, 3200L, 2867L, 
    1778L, 1169L, 1215L, 1262L, 1461L, 1600L, 1692L, 4978L, 1760L, 
    2019L, 2650L, 2827L, 2356L, 1800L, 2840L, 2063L, 2248L, 1948L, 
    2160L, 1733L, 2296L, 2677L, 2100L, 2640L, 2655L, 3950L, 2210L, 
    2848L, 2543L), MAP = c(80L, 65L, 86L, 74L, 67L, 65L, 74L, 
    90L, 70L, 90L, 96L, 94L, 100L, 82L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 69L, 
    71L, 70L, 71L, 77L, 73L, 75L, 77L, 61L, 85L, 65L, 74L, 70L, 
    67L, 69L, 74L, 92L, 71L, 88L, 93L, 89L, 79L, 97L, 97L), CVP = c(10L, 
    8L, 21L, 19L, 15L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 
    22L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 24L, 20L, 22L, 
    24L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 17L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 22L, 
    20L, 20L, 21L, 8L, 8L), PAP = c(23L, 22L, 36L, 36L, 34L, 
    32L, 22L, 33L, 28L, 36L, 36L, 40L, 37L, 37L, 40L, 35L, 35L, 
    34L, 38L, 36L, 45L, 43L, 55L, 49L, 52L, 54L, 43L, 47L, 27L, 
    25L, 23L, 22L, 28L, 21L, 20L, 25L, 33L, 33L, 38L, 35L, 33L, 
    29L), PCWP = c(15L, 11L, 28L, 26L, 23L, 21L, 11L, 26L, NA, 
    NA, 25L, 25L, NA, 27L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Name", "Time", "Dobut", 
"DobutDose", "CI", "SvO2", "SVRI", "MAP", "CVP", "PAP", "PCWP"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L))
```

Now the first `xyplot` I made for the variable `CI` looks like this

```
require(lattice)
xyplot(CI~Time, groups=Name, data=df, ty=c("l", "p"),
+        ,xlab="Measurement Time Point", 
ylab=expression("CI"~(l/min/m^"2")), main="Cardiac Index")
```

[image: First xyplot]

Now I was able to add the mean (black line) of the whole cohort, by doing the following

```
xyplot(CI~Time, groups=Name, data=df, ty=c("l", "p"), 
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.linejoin(x, y, horizontal = FALSE,..., col="black", lty=1, lwd=4)
       }
       ,xlab="Measurement Time Point", 
ylab=expression("CI"~(l/min/m^"2")), main="Cardiac Index")
```

[image: Second xyplot]

Now I'd like to add +/- SE to the mean as a line above/below the mean, but nowhere can I find how to do this.

What I can do is using the `latticeExtra` package is add the loess line +/- SE, as below, but that's not the correct mathematical function I'm looking for. I've left the mean line in there to illustrate the difference between the two.

```
require(latticeExtra)
xyplot(CI~Time, groups=Name, data=df, ty=c("l", "p"), 
+        panel = function(x, y, ...) {
+            panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
+            panel.linejoin(x, y, horizontal = FALSE,..., col="black", lty=1, lwd=4)
+            panel.smoother(x,y,se=TRUE, col.se="grey")
+        }
+        ,xlab="Measurement Time Point", 
ylab=expression("CI"~(l/min/m^"2")), main="Cardiac Index")
```

[image: Third xyplot]

I have performed an extensive search through SO and the internet, but I haven't been able to find the right function to do this.

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What standard error do you want to plot exactly? Do you just want to plot the SE for all points at a given measurement time point? There is no function in `lattice` that will calculate that value for you. You will need to calculate it yourself and then draw it in you custom panel function. Do you want to plot it like a ribbon?

Comment: Thanks. The SE I'd want is as you say: for all measurements at a given timepoint (T1-T8). Kind of like the loess function, but basically the mean +/- SEM at each time-point and the connection of the points being the mean. 
I computed a separate `data.frame` with all the values of interest, but wasn't able to "overlay" it on the `xyplot`. If you want a quick function for the SE here's one: 
`stderr<-function(x) sqrt(var(x,na.rm=TRUE)/length(na.omit(x)))`. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own panel function to plot a +/- SD region. For example

```
#new panel function
panel.se <- function(x, y, col.se=plot.line$col, alpha.se=.25, ...) {
    plot.line <- trellis.par.get("plot.line")
    xs <- if(is.factor(x)) {
       factor(c(levels(x) , rev(levels(x))), levels=levels(x))
    } else {
       xx <- sort(unique(x))
       c(xx, rev(xx))
    }
    means <- tapply(y,x, mean, na.rm=T)
    vars <- tapply(y,x, var, na.rm=T)
    Ns <- tapply(!is.na(y),x, sum)
    ses <- sqrt(vars/Ns)
    panel.polygon(xs, c(means+ses, rev(means-ses)), col=col.se, alpha=alpha.se)
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
#include new panel function
xyplot(CI~Time, groups=Name, data=df, ty=c("l", "p"), 
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.se(x,y, col.se="grey")
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.linejoin(x, y, horizontal = FALSE,..., col="black", lty=1, lwd=4)

       }
       ,xlab="Measurement Time Point", 
ylab=expression("CI"~(l/min/m^"2")), main="Cardiac Index")
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: HA! What a man Mr. Flick! This is quite awesome! Thank you! I was thinking that I would have to create a new panel which also included the `tapply` function. Now reading your code closely, am I right in the assumption, that we are plotting the standard deviation and not standard error of mean? I tried re-writing your code to include the `stderr` function I posted above, but I get an error message. Sorry to keep bugging you, but seeing that you've just solved my daylong problem, I'm very excited!!!

Comment: I've updated based on your definition of "standard error". I'm assuming that will fix the error message but since you didn't show your code or even give the exact error message, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Actually a side comment: I managed to get the code to work, by adding the `stderr` function, but removing the `na.rm=T`in the `panel.sd` function...that's quite bizzare actually! But seeing, that the `stderr` function has a `na.rm=T` in it and the `NAs` only affect the computation of the SE and SD (but not the mean), I think it would be ok, don't you?

Comment: The code that produces the error message: `Error using paket 1 unused argument na.rm=TRUE`

`panel.sem <- function(x, y, col.se=plot.line$col, alpha.se=.10, ...) {
+     plot.line <- trellis.par.get("plot.line")
+     xs <- if(is.factor(x)) {
+         factor(c(levels(x) , rev(levels(x))), levels=levels(x))
+     } else {
+         xx <- sort(unique(x))
+         c(xx, rev(xx))
+     }
+     means <- tapply(y,x, mean, na.rm=T)
+     stderr <- tapply(y,x, stderr, na.rm=T)
+     panel.polygon(xs, c(means+stderr, rev(means-stderr)), col=col.se, alpha=alpha.se)`

See how to fix it above. Thanks!