# Add standard deviation as grey smoothed bands to lattice xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

It's quite a time I am trying to resolve this question and I can't figure it out... I am sure it's quite simple.
I would like to add the +/- MM standard deviation (column SD.MM) to my MM line as a line above/below it and the same for the KK one. 
Here is my data

```
data <- read.table(textConnection(
    "Day         Period  MM      KK     SD.MM   SD.KK
1   Tuesday     1   20.0    131.0   1.74    11.40
2   Tuesday     2   76.8    203.0   10.60   28.10
3   Tuesday     3   26.7    118.0   13.00   57.50
4   Wednesday   1   33.8    143.0   2.64    11.20
5   Wednesday   2   74.1    232.0   10.30   32.60
6   Wednesday   3   34.0    130.0   17.60   67.00
7   Thursday    1   46.4    203.0   3.95    16.80
8   Thursday    2   59.5    165.0   8.26    23.10
9   Thursday    3   32.1    120.0   16.50   61.90
10  Friday      1   24.6    98.8    1.96    7.95
11  Friday      2   139.0   367.0   18.20   47.90
12  Friday      3   91.4    216.0   20.90   49.40
13  Saturday    1   30.6    158.0   2.42    11.60
14  Saturday    2   78.2    295.0   8.02    33.40
15  Saturday    3   90.7    310.0   51.60   176.00
16  Sunday      1   28.0    115.0   2.47    9.91
17  Sunday      2   80.4    232.0   10.90   30.40
18  Sunday      3   42.5    211.0   19.70   97.80"),
header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)
```

Here the code for producing the image below it.

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)
a <- xyplot(MM~Period|Day,data=data,layout=c(6,1), type="o", 
            xlab="Period", 
            ylab="Loads",
            ylab.right = "Loads",
            main ="Daily trend",
            index.cond=list(c(5,6,4, 1:3)),
            ylim = c(0,150),
            scales=list(x=list(at=seq(1,3,1),labels=c("B","F","A")),
                        y=(list(alternating=3))),
            key = list(text = list("MM"), points = list(pch=1, col="steelblue2"),
                       text = list("KK"), points = list(pch=1, col="violet"),
                       text = list("d-KK = 306"), lines = list(lty=4, lwd=2, col="green4"),
                       text = list("u-KK = 312"), lines = list(lty=4, lwd=2, col="red"),
                       text = list("s-KK = 41"), lines = list(lty=4, lwd=2, col="gold"),
                       border = F
            )
)

b <- xyplot(KK~Period|Day,data=data,layout=c(6,1), type="o", col="violet",
            xlab="Period", 
            ylab="Loads",
            ylab.right = "Loads",
            index.cond=list(c(5,6,4, 1:3)), 
            ylim = c(0,400),
            scales=list(x=list(at=seq(1,3,1),labels=c("B","F","A")),
                        y=(list(alternating=3))),
            panel = function(x,y,...) {
              panel.abline(h=306,lty = 4, lwd=2, col="green4")
              panel.abline(h = 312, lty = 4, lwd=2, col="red")
              panel.abline(h = 41, lty = 4, lwd=2, col="gold")
              panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
            }
)
grid.arrange(a,b, nrow=2)
```

[image: MM and KK xyplot]

I would like something resulting like the grey band on the xyplot here [R - Lattice xyplot - How do you add error bars to groups and summary lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332489/r-lattice-xyplot-how-do-you-add-error-bars-to-groups-and-summary-lines).

Any help ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a tricky one with creating a gray smooth lines - your best bid is to play with `panel.smoother` from [`latticeExtra` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latticeExtra/index.html), but it has a lot of weird parameters so its not easy to hack it out of box.

However, doing typical standard deviation bars from your data is easy with `xYplot` from [`Hmisc` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html).

First, you have to define lower and upper limits for your standard deviation bars based on your corresponding data. I just use your standard deviation symmetrically on both sides of the values, but you can divide it by two depending on how you calculated it:

```
data$MM_sd_hi <- data$MM+data$SD.MM  
data$MM_sd_low <- data$MM-data$SD.MM  
data$KK_sd_hi <- data$KK+data$SD.KK  
data$KK_sd_low <- data$KK-data$SD.KK
```

Than you add those limits within `Cbind` function inside `xYplot`. You need to increase your `ylim` a bit more to accommodate this, because `xYplot` does something weird with scales. Here is the code:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(gridExtra)
a <- xYplot(Cbind(MM, MM_sd_low, MM_sd_hi)~Period | Day, data=data, layout=c(6,1), 
            type="o", xlab="Period",ylab="Loads", ylab.right = "Loads", 
            main ="Daily trend", index.cond=list(c(5,6,4, 1:3)), ylim = c(0,170),
            scales=list(x=list(at=seq(1,3,1),labels=c("B","F","A")),
                        y=(list(alternating=3))),
            key = list(text = list("MM"), points = list(pch=1, col="steelblue2"),
                       text = list("KK"), points = list(pch=1, col="violet"),
                       text = list("d-KK = 306"), lines = list(lty=4, lwd=2, col="green4"),
                       text = list("u-KK = 312"), lines = list(lty=4, lwd=2, col="red"),
                       text = list("s-KK = 41"), lines = list(lty=4, lwd=2, col="gold"),
                       border = F)
           )   

b <- xYplot(Cbind(KK, KK_sd_low, KK_sd_hi)~Period|Day,data=data,layout=c(6,1), 
            type="o", col="violet", xlab="Period", ylab="Loads", ylab.right = "Loads",
            index.cond=list(c(5,6,4, 1:3)), ylim = c(0,500),
            scales=list(x=list(at=seq(1,3,1),labels=c("B","F","A")),
                        y=(list(alternating=3))),
            panel = function(x,y,...) {
              panel.abline(h=306,lty = 4, lwd=2, col="green4")
              panel.abline(h = 312, lty = 4, lwd=2, col="red")
              panel.abline(h = 41, lty = 4, lwd=2, col="gold")
              panel.xYplot(x,y,...)
            }
)
grid.arrange(a,b, nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much ! this is not what I wanted at the beginning but it is solving my problem which was showing the sd :)